# Python package import image not found MacOS

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I am having tremendous difficulty with a supposedly menial task.

I have installed `pyodbc` using `pip3` but can't import it.

Here is the package:

```
(Django) FTCadms-MacBook-Pro:RiskLab blah$ pip3 show pyodbc
Name: pyodbc
Version: 4.0.30
Summary: DB API Module for ODBC
Home-page: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: MIT
Location: /Users/blah/Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

When I run `python3` and try to `import pyodcb` I get the error `image not found`:

```
(Django) FTCadms-MacBook-Pro:RiskLab blah$ python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:26)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/blah/Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library
 not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/blah/Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
>>>
```

I have found a few suggestions saying I need to recompile odbc which I am pretty sure should not be the best solution.

Comment: You don't have unixODBC or it's in a non-standard location. Some fixes for the latter:  https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/681 From the pyodcb github

Comment: `brew install unixodbc`?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up and did what I was trying to avoid from the start, which was installing Anaconda.

This solves the issue, but it does not explain it..